# Finding out where a function was defined in zsh

Tags: function, shell, metadata, zsh

Is it possible for me to query the definition location of a function in zsh? Does zsh store such metadata about functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, zsh stores the functions internally, but I guess you want to know where zsh read the function from. This can be shown by:

```
whence -v FUNCTIONNAME
```